# How to generate testing report in JUNIT in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, junit

I am using `Selenium webdriver 2.0` in `JUnit` framework. I need to generate a report on my tuned both (positive and negative) test cases.

NOTE: We have an option to generate report by default in "TESTNG" framework. I need a solution to create in `JUnit`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether you were using Ant or something else.  I will assume you are more interested in the "positive and negative" part of the question than how to invoke the JUnit test runner from your build tool.

You can register a [TestWatcher](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) to monitor what happens during a test run.  The JUnit test runner will invoke methods on the TestWatcher when significant events occur.  You can override those methods to insert logging code for passing/failing tests.  Here is some sample code:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
public class positive {   
    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e,Description d) {
        System.out.println("FAILED: "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description d) {
        System.out.println("PASSED: "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void fails() {
    Assert.fail("I am a failure");
    }

    @Test
    public void passes() {
    }
}
```

When you run that from the command line, you will see something like this:

```
$ java -cp $HOME/software/junit/target/*:$HOME/software/junit/lib/*:$PWD org.junit.runner.JUnitCore positive
JUnit version 4.12-SNAPSHOT
.PASSED: positive.passes
.FAILED: positive.fails
E
Time: 0.007
There was 1 failure:
1) fails(positive)
java.lang.AssertionError: I am a failure
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at positive.fails(positive.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [etc.]

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 2,  Failures: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With Junit you can use ant to generate the reports in a html file. you have to configure the build.xml in ant to get the results in html.

Comment: and here is the and task to do this - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html